# handlebar light (or mount) with ball and socket joint

Tags: product-rec, handlebars, headlights

Is there a handlebar light or mount that uses a ball and socket joint or otherwise allows complete freedom to change where it points? I like to adjust my light depending on a # of factors. For example, as I approach someone on the trail, I'll adjust the light down and to the right to avoid blinding them. Sometimes I'll want it more up (in areas with branches at head level) or to the side (for an upcoming turn). And so on.

I've been unable to find a product providing this kind of adjustability.

In contrast, handlebar mirrors often have such joints. Currently, I rubberband a flashlight to the back of my mirror at night. The mirror joint has enough strength to hold the additional weight of the light and yet lets me adjust it just by pushing. No tools required. I've been doing this for a while so I could continue but it takes some attention - rubber bands only last a few days in the sun so I have to check them before each ride, and strapping it on is a bit of a nuisance. I'd prefer something that I could just snap on/off. Or maybe I just need to find some kind of "better rubberband" that is more reliable and stands up to weather? (I've looked for that too without success. Velcro won't work - it has to have some stretch because the mirror doesn't mate perfectly with the flashlight.)

Please don't suggest a headlamp. (I avoid headlamps. I've tried them. I regularly ride/run with others and they are frequently blinding me and each other, etc.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: My last few front lights have had an o-ring round the bars. That allows the up-down adjustment you want (I also dip my lights as required). I find a suitable headlamp angled appropriately to be a useful addition, but I agree with you that it's not the solution.

Comment: Decent light with good optics, providing a low but wide beam will cover the turns and the mount can rotate around the bars for height adjustment. A dual beam or two lamps could give you a "high/low" set up like cars.   
refer https://www.bikelightdatabase.com

Comment: I know you've excluded headlamps, but I like them.  The trick is to aim them so your normal riding position points the light in the 2-3 metres in front of your wheel.  Headlamps should not point away down the road.  If you want to illuminate there, then you consciously have to look up a bit.   Mine's a really tight focussed spot, and only lights up what I want to see.   Small bonus, on my camera the recording shows exactly where my head is aimed.

Comment: Also - more is better.  I run four discreet front lights (head, two bar, and a fork light) and 5 rear (helmet, bag, pocket, seat post, and low seatstay)   Don't bank on just one.

Answer (score 2):

Philips Saferide came with a ball and socket mount. The light has been discontinued though. Possibly you can get replacement mounts and adapt them: [Philips page for holder](http://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/BA003X1/led-bike-lights-bikelight-3d-handlebar-holder).

[image: Philips Saferide mount]

Personally I'd look for something that uses a rubber strap to hold it onto the handlebar, loose enough that you can move it to point up and down, but tight enough to stay stable when moved. Adjusting the Philips ball and socket to work that way, instead of setting aim once and then tightening to lock, could be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be better.

Ball joints tend to fail when subject to vibration, and more so when on the end of an arm/pole.

These things rotate 360 degrees and work fairly well.  Personally I'd use a wrist strap around the handlebars as well, as a secondary fastening.

[image]

This one found at http://www.dx.com/p/bicycle-lamp-silicone-clip-flashlight-holder-black-434542   but there are heaps of similar things.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a light designed to be attached to a bike, instead of a flashlight.

I have a Light and Motion headlight similar to the one below. It attaches to my handlebars with a rubber loop. It's nothing fancy, but does what you want. It swivels left and right, and can move up and down by twisting around the bars (the strap grips the bar pretty tight, but it's easy enough to push down to turn your "high-beams" off).

I think I paid 65 USD for it. I was a bit hesitant to spend so much money on something I didn't really need (at the time), but it was totally worth it, much better than a flashlight and duct tape, or a headlamp.

[image: Light and Motion headlight]